# Image along with text in HTML, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I am using asp.net and C#.

I have a image and three line. Which I want to place like this

Like the one you can see in this below URL .

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/gallery/

Image is on the left side and parallel to image we can write text.

I know that the same can be acheived by HTML table / ASP.NET table like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
    <img src="#"/>
   </td>
   <td>
    first line <br />
    second line <br/>
    third line <br />
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

but my problem is that I can't use table, so please let me know how can i acheive the above task without using tables.

Might be `<span>` or `<div>` tag can do the trick. but I am really dumb in html. and I can't ever search the exact answer to my problem on google..

Comment: I wrote the HTML content on the above post, but god knows why it is not appearing. let me try it again..
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
   <img src="xyz" />
   </td>
   <td>
   Text Test asdkahsd <br />
   asjkdlalsdjljaljsdljaljdsljlasjd <br />
   ;kk;aksd;ka;sd;ka;dk;ka;ksd;ka;ksd;k;aksd <br />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

Comment: To have HTML or any code appear, highlight the code on the edit page, and click the '101' button.

Comment: Thanks waiwai, your comment will help me in future ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS, you can float the image to the left, which will cause the text to appear to the image's right.

For example, take the following:

```
<html>
<head><title>Example</title></head>
<body>
    <div style="float:left"> <!-- I've floated the div containing the image to the left -->
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo13.png">
    </div>
This is text that is to the right of the image. 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Absolute perfect .. :)
thanks alot for your quick response ...

work like miracle for me. Thanks again

Comment: With a class assigned to the image or via some other selector, you can float the image without wrapping it in a div.  Also, while I am sure waiwai933 used inline styles for brevity, you are better off putting the styles in a stylesheet.

Comment: Hi Waiwai & BJ Safdie,

I have used the same code , it's working fine in IE and Chrome but not working in firefox, any suggestion ??

In firefox, text is going under the image

Please help.

Comment: @Zero It works for me on Firefox. Do you have a link to a page where it's not working?

Comment: I am developing application on my local host, if it is working for you then might be there is some mistake in my html code. Let me check it. After some day I am going to deploy my site, if the issue reoccurs .. may i contact you at that time, so that you can provide your valuable feedback.
Thanks.